# Density of sum of uniform distributions on $[-1, 1]$ (Irwin-Hall)

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, solution-verification, linear-transformations, density-function

The Irwin-Hall distribution is the distribution of a sum of $n$ independent uniformly distributed random variables on the interval $[0, 1]$.
The PDF for the Irwin-Hall distribution is
$$
\frac{1}{2\left(n-1\right)!}\sum_{k=0}^{n}\left(-1\right)^{k}{n \choose k}\left(x-k\right)^{n-1}\operatorname{sgn}\left(x-k\right)
$$
I want the sum of $n$ uniform variables on the interval $[-1, 1]$ (not $[0, 1]$). Denote the Irwin-Hall distribution with uniform distributions on interval $[a, b]$ by $\text{IH}[a, b]$. Then,
$$
\text{IH}[-1, 1] = \sum_{k=1}^n \text{Uniform}[-1, 1] = \sum_{k=1}^n (-1 + 2 \cdot \text{Uniform}[-1, 1])
= -n + 2\cdot \text{IH}[0, 1]
$$
Now, applying a linear transformation, we get the PDF of $\text{IH}[-1, 1]$ to be
$$
\frac{1}{2}f\left(\frac{x + n}{2}\right)
$$
where $f$ is the PDF of $\text{IH}[0, 1]$.

I am unsure about the correctness of this. Could you please verify it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is correct. Let $X_1,\ldots,X_n$ be independent and uniformly distributed on $[-1, 1]$, with $X = X_1 + \ldots + X_n$, so $X$ has the modified Irwin-Hall distribution you define. Pick a tiny interval $[x, x+\epsilon] \subseteq [-1, 1]$. Since each $\frac{X_i + 1}{2}$ is uniform on $[0, 1]$, their sum $\frac{X+n}{2}$ has the usual Irwin-Hall distribution. The probability that $X$ falls in $[x, x+\epsilon]$ is equal to the probability that $\frac{X+n}{2}$ falls in $[\frac{x+n}{2}, \frac{x+\epsilon+n}{2}]$. For small $\epsilon$, this is approximately the length of the interval $[\frac{x+n}{2}, \frac{x+\epsilon+n}{2}]$ times the density $f$ of the usual Irwin-Hall distribution at the left endpoint. The result is a probability of about $\frac{\epsilon}{2} f(\frac{x+n}{2})$.

Given the probability that $X$ lies on the interval $[x, x+\epsilon]$, we can now obtain the density of $X$ at $x$ by dividing by $\epsilon$. The answer won't be exactly correct for any positive $\epsilon$ but the limit as $\epsilon \rightarrow 0$ is the true density. Thus we compute that indeed, the density of the modified distribution is $\frac{1}{2} f(\frac{x+n}{2})$.